# Unable to locate the element in eclipse using xpath, though i am able to locate with the same in the console

Tags: selenium

Using below xpath:

// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='cell small-4 ui-sortable-handle']/child::a/child::p[1]/i[@title='Content Blocks']")).click();

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please take the time to show us your code, Xpath is useless without the underlying data you're trying to browse. You would also need to include expected behaviour.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML.